# Add service methods to queue for loading additional data to cache

Tags: java, spring, queue, scheduling, background-process

I have several service classes (CustomerService, AgreementService). Each method result is cached using ehcache.

Some calls of service methods are pretty expensive or take long to run.

When I'm loading e.g. customer I know that there is great possibility that customers agreements will be required next. So I need to load them to cache on background and make application more responsible.

I've tried using aspects. I've set pointcut to CustomerService.getById(id) method and @AfterReturning advice.

```
@AfterReturning(
    pointcut = "execution(* com.example.CustomerService.getById(..))", 
    returning = "result"
)
public void loadCustomerAgreements(Object result) {
    Customer customer = (Customer) result;
    // calls method which caches result into ehcache
    agreementService.findByCustomer(customer.getId());
}
```

Unfortunately this solution loads customer and its agreements at once (which is not desirable because of long response). I would like instead to load customer and return to user. Then asynchronously load agreements.

For that purpose advice `@After` works great. But I can't get customer identification so I don't know which agreements to load.

Is there a way how to do this using aspects or any Spring trigger or other technology?

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that method run by aspect was blocking further program execution because it was executed in same thread. The possible solution can be to run aspect method asynchronously using Spring Task Execution framework.

Spring configuration can look like this:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="executorWithPoolSizeRange" scheduler="taskScheduler"/>
<task:executor id="executorWithPoolSizeRange" pool-size="5-25" queue-capacity="100"/>
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="1"/>
```

Then aspect will look like:

```
@Async
@AfterReturning(
    pointcut = "execution(* com.example.CustomerService.getById(..))", 
    returning = "result"
)
public void loadCustomerAgreements(Object result) {
    Customer customer = (Customer) result;
    // calls method which caches result into ehcache
    agreementService.findByCustomer(customer.getId());
}
```

this will run `loadCustomerAgreements()` method in different thread if there is any free thread available.

For more information see:

- http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html
- http://krams915.blogspot.cz/2011/01/spring-3-task-scheduling-via.html